# Friend is unable to ping my IP or connect to me directly in any way

Tags: networking, ping, p2p

I have the following setup:

- Docsis 3.0 modem running in bridge mode
- ASUS RT-N12 router
- Windows 10 PC connected directly to the modem, NOT connected to the ASUS router. Has Avira installed, but the only firewall running is Windows Defender
- Macbook Pro connected to the ASUS router

I have 5 friends I play a game online with where one person hosts and the others all connect directly. Four of them are able to connect to me with no issues, but as of a few weeks ago, the fifth one can no longer connect to me at all. If any of the others host, he can connect to them just fine. It's just me he can't connect to.

My desktop, laptop, and bridge's public IP addresses are all distinct but start with the same three octets. He can ping the bridge, but not either of the computers. I'm primarily concerned with connecting to him with the Windows computer connected directly to the bridge.

My Windows Defender is configured to always allow connections from his IP address. Even when my firewall is disabled, he still can't connect to me. The bridge config does not have any connection blocking or whitelisting properties whatsoever.

I contacted my ISP and they stated that they do not block incoming requests from specific IPs at the ISP level.

He ran `tracert` on my desktop's IP address, and it only returned one line that reads `192.168.0.1 reports: Destination protocol unreachable.`

Is this likely a problem on my end, or his end? If it's on my end, what can be done to allow him to connect to me?

Comment: 192.168.0.1 only exists while connected to your network

Comment: @Ramhound I know, it's just the only line he's seeing when he tries to run tracert to my public IP. He showed me a screenshot indicating such.

Comment: Your friend attempted to **tracert** on an IP address that doesn’t exist within his intranet network, it appears, your friend attempted to **tracert** on 192.168.0.1 which doesn exist within his network

Comment: @Ramhound: No, it appears that you're entirely misinterpreting the tracert error message.

Comment: You will need to edit your question and include additional information before anyone can answer your question

Comment: What additional info will help? He didn't ping 192.168.0.1, he pinged my IP address. I won't share the screenshot because it contains my public IP address, but it is very clearly what he ran tracert on. The 192.168.0.1 error message is the first leg of tracert, at which it aborted.

Comment: The error strongly implies an issue on his side - probably on his router.

Comment: Putting a router between my PC and the modem fixed the issue. I wish I could explain how.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this user can no longer replicate this problem. Nor do I think he understood what the problem was in the first place...